# Can we post a comment where we think the question should go to a proposal on area 51 where it fits the best?

Tags: discussion, on-topic, professional

I just want to know if we can post a comment on a question stating "This question can be best suited for the area 51 proposal i.e. XYZ on this particular topic..." Coz I think this will also help the user to get to the expert answers and will also help the proposal.

No intentions of pulling users from any of the current sites to new proposals but to give a chance to proposal by reaching out to the right audience! Because this could be beneficial to all users.

Please advice!!

Answer (score 3):

People usually post questions because they want answers, and Area 51 proposal questions don't get answers.

If the question is in scope here, then there is no reason to suggest moving it.

You might also post a comment telling someone about an existing Area 51 if there is reason to suspect they will be interested. This is something that should be done in moderation.  Chat is a better place for discussions about Area 51 proposals.

In this case though I suspect you are discussing the proposal for [Aquariums Fish & reef keepers](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/79786/aquariums-fish-reef-keepers) I had not realized it was still active.

I have posted [What is in scope at 'Aquariums Fish & reef keepers' that is not in scope at Pets or Biology?](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19220/what-is-in-scope-at-aquariums-fish-reef-keepers-that-is-not-in-scope-at-pets) as subset of an existing site, there is a very high standard to meet for the creation of the proposal.

Answer (score 0):

There is no reason why you cannot post a comment pointing someone at an Area51 proposal.

On one hand, it won't get an answer if posted there - as has already been pointed out.  Indeed if someone were to answer it, that answer may well get deleted.

On the other hand, it may draw attention to the Area51 proposal.  This might help it graduate to Beta.

So the answer depends upon whether you wish to help the proposal to proceed to the next stage.